# Code Igniter - Best Practice for views to not violate DRY

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, dry

Trying to determine the best way to handle views in codeigniter. Right now anything I consider seems too messy.

Currently I have 3 relevent views:

1) Header
2) Content
3) footer

Every single controller has something like this. Some controllers even have this several times (different functions in the same controller):

```
$this->load->view('head', $data);
$this->load->view('volunteers/add_profile.php',$content_data);
$this->load->view('foot');
```

It seems pretty silly to have to load header and footer on EVERY single page. However, each page will have slightly different data in the header (meta tags, style sheets, loaded scripts, etc).

Is there a cleaner way for me to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: look at my answer(user2727841) it will give you a idea!!!

Comment: Check the answer of @user2727841...

Answer (score 4):

I like to create a parent controller with a method like `renderPage('content_view', $data)`.  That method can include the header, menu, footer, ...  That way, all the view loading stuff is kept in the controller and I don't have to bother with header, menu or footer on every action or view.  It's also flexible as your child controllers can redefine the `renderPage()` method to fit their purposes.

If you need to load multiple content views, you could create a `renderPage()` method that takes in an array of string instead of a string.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - have a template view. In your controller:

```
$data['header'] = xxx;
$data['content'] = xxx;
$this->load->view('my_template', $data);
```

Then in your my_template.php view file:

```
$this->load->view('head', $header);
$this->load->view('volunteers/add_profile.php',$content);
$this->load->view('foot');
```

Comment: How does $header data get from the controler to the my_template.php view file?

Comment: you cannt you $this->load inside view file !

Comment: @MomenMElZalabany yes you can. I do it all the time

Answer (score 1):

Either what @TheShiftExchange suggested, or, if your application allows it, you can call header and footer views from each content view (which is the only view called from the controller then).

Answer (score 0):

I've created my own controller where I create `MY_Controller extends CI_Controller` class then in `MY_Controller` I use access modifier `$data` and `$loadviewArray`.

```
public $data = array(); 
public $loadviewArray = array();
```

after this I create function in `MY_Controller`

```
public function loadview() {
   foreach ($this->loadviewArray as $key => $val) {
      $this->load->view($val, $this->data);
   }
}
```

then I create controller `Admin` and `extends` `MY_Controller` like this `Admin extends MY_Controller` in `Admin` controller create function `index`.

```
public function index() {
   $this->data["page_title"] = "Login";
   $this->data["records"] = $data; // You can pass data
   $this->loadviewArray = array("admin/header", "admin/login", "admin/footer");
   $this->loadview();
}
```

In `$data` access modifier array I pass data at views and in `$loadviewArray` load views then call a function for loading views you can do like this also its very helpful for me now. And create header and footer views seperate...

Comment: that also works, and if you want to load another view inside lets say admin/login you can use $data['extra']=$this->load->view('view',$data,True); ! or somthing;;

Answer (score -1):

please check https://github.com/alzalabany/codeigniter-base-controller/tree/master

So you can always use a templating lib. yet i dont like them for some reason !

codeigniter allow you to extend its core; if you go to link mentioned above u can see a small example

in this example every controller that will extend MY_controller will start with these defauls

```
protected        $body='base/body',
                        $title='Codeigniter Z master',//txt
                        $js=array(),//filename
                        $inline_js='',//script
                        $css=array(),
                        $inline_css='',//style
                        $breadcrumb=FALSE,//<li><a>
                        $content=array(),//html
                        $noEcho = FALSE;
```

so if u chose to change them in MY_controller its effect will be default, otherwise use $this->title = 'Codeigniter - welcome page'; in ur controller constructor for example;

loading assist is a very easy job just call `$this->_assets()` and location of asset (edit MY_controller.php default location to you assets folder); if its an inline_js/css just call

```
$this->_assets('alert("hi");','js');
```

if you want to load a view into a page section use `$this->outv(view_path,view_data,section_name);`

and if you want to just load html into a variable u can use

$this->out('Footer','footer');

at end just call ->_flush();

some other options i use like

`$noEcho` ; if set it will clear all buffer to remove any echo's before it send your view content to browser;

you can also set functions like log-out or log-in inside MY_controller and it will be accessible by any of ur controllers `http://localhost/ci/welcome/logout`

any way :) i hope that answers your question !

Comment: any reason for down voting ?